# Meaning of "For, as to their own happiness, it is but trash"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the sentence in bold?

> I don't think happiness is important. **For, as to their own
>   happiness, it is but trash.** To what end is happiness?, I say. Henry
>   Jacobson (Happiness)

Comment: Do you want an interpretation of only the bold part?

Comment: @username901345 Sounds like Howard Jacobson to me - (eg http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/commentators/howard-jacobson/howard-jacobson-how-happiness-can-inspire-great-art-2132870.html). Happiness is one of his themes, but I'd need a context to make sense of it. Can you provide one?

Answer (score 3):

I would say the utterance is clumsy phrasing. Grammatically *and* semantically, it would be fine if Jacobson had said *"... as to **one's** own happiness ..."*, but *"**their**"* doesn't really work there.

This use of the *"as to X"* construction is a shorthand way of saying *"focussing [specifically] on X"*. It's normally used when the observation that follows (*"happiness is but trash"*, here) is only really true *if considered in that specific context*. Since Jacobson has already asserted that happiness is not important, it seems utterly pointless to restrict the second assertion in that way.

I think he uses the "restricting" clause because what he actually means is *"One's own happiness is but trash"* - but he thinks *"**one's**"* is "starchy/formal", so he wants a more "colloquial/informal" alternative. Which doesn't work, because there's no prior referent against which to attach the possessive pronoun.

We can make a perfectly good standalone assertion using *"**one's**"* with no prior referent...

> 1: *When attending an interview, one's fingernails should always be clean.*

...where *"one"* is just *"any [unspecified] person who attends an interview"*. But...

> 2: When attending an interview, their fingernails should always be clean.

...just leaves us wondering *"What? - who on earth are **they**?"*

---

TL;DR: It means *"[Preoccupation with] one's own happiness is [just, merely, nothing **but**] trash"*. The initial ***for*** simply means ***because*** (i.e. - the second sentence is supposed to "explain" the first).

Comment: Eh, +1. This seems as good of an interpretation as any given the ridiculously small amount context we have to work with.